# What does the custom parameter HL stand for?

Tags: firebase-authentication

On [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#set-custom-parameters) page a couple of custom parameters are listed that you can use when authenticating with Google in your Firebase application. One of the parameters is hd, which stands for hosted domain. I am looking for an option to allow authentication for a list of specific domains. I see there is a parameter hl and I was wondering what it stand for and how it can be used. I cannot find anything on this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hl` in Google OAuth flow is used for localization. For example, passing `it` value for `hl` will localize the UI to Italian.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({hl: 'it'});
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```